# Dont dequeue if the transaction is not complete- Apache Camel-ActiveMQ

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using camel route for consuming the message from the queue for every 5 minutes and processing it.

While processing, if there are any exceptions,the camel/activemq  sends the messages to the we .DLQ as I am using the client_acknowledge as given below, however I need to have the messages in the same queue(not to send to DLQ) in case of failures in case of processing errors.

Need help in how should I configure my route or component to meet that requirement.

```
from("jms:queue:test?receiveTimeout=5000&acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE").
    log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Consuming message from test : ")
   .to("direct:MyProcessingRoute");
```

Comment: You can configure ActiveMQ to allow a higher number of redelivery before a message is moved to a DLQ.